# Proxying a Call via Twilio

Tags: api, proxy, twilio

How can I use Twilio as a proxy between a caller and a callee to keep the phone number of the callee private from the caller?

A bonus feature would be to transcribe the call automatically, but I am still new to the Twilio API.

Answer (score 6):

You may also use the [TwiML <Dial>](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) tag to connect a call in progress with another phone number.  You can specify a callerId attribute to set the outgoing callerId to any incoming phone number you have purchased from Twilio or any phone number you have verified with Twilio.  Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="123-456-7890">415-123-4567</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity and it's also slightly cheaper at 0.03/minute instead of 0.04 as above.

Answer (score 5):

The best approach to accomplish this is to use create two outbound calls using the REST api and direct both uses back to TwiML joining them to the same conference.  Here's an example of what the call code would look like in Python.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
account = "AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
caller_id = "+15555555555"
client = TwilioRestClient(account, token)
first_call = client.calls.create(to="+1{First Phone Number}", from_=caller_id,
                       url="http://path/to/twiml.xml")
second_call = client.calls.create(to="+1{Second Phone Number}", from_=caller_id,
                       url="http://path/to/twiml.xml")
```

And for your Twiml, simply put:

```
<Response>
    <Say>You are now entering the conference line.</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Conference>foo</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Voila - both parties only see the phone number you specify in caller_id.

Comment: awesome. If I want to divulge the caller's number to the callee, should I set caller_id to the caller's number, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: No, called_id must be a number that is registered (or purchased) through twilio.

Answer (score 0):

2020 update for anyone still searching & finding for this: Twilio now has a [Proxy API](https://www.twilio.com/proxy).